# Weird for each loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

Hate to bug you but I have the unpleasant task of sifting through another mans code to come up with fixes. Its a PHP site using a smarty template renderer. On a page is perfectly good function piece of code but for the life of me I cannot figure out how its done:

```
{foreach item=count from=$page}
    {foreach item=user from=$count}
```

Now I get the loop part but what I dont get is why the 'item' variable is not declared and where the heck the 'from' fits into the picture. I have hunted all over the web and in the PHP site manual but can find no answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not PHP. I'm not experienced with Smarty, maybe that's what that is.

Comment: That is from Smarty... http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl I have only ever worked with it a handful of times myself. A lot of times when working with a "good" programmer that used smarty you will find they did the example.tpl and example.php which will deal with the tpl variables.

Comment: Thanks guys, managed a work around.